# Why is Unity WebGL not working on my React Website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have been trying to import a Unity game inside of my website using React Unity WebGL. I have looked at many tutorials and videos and I seem to have the right code however, the games do not show up on my website (Images attached of code and website). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

[My Game.tsx file which I use in my Game.js file]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWknb.png)

[My Game.js file]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/10dFe.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you get any errors in your developer tools console?

Comment: @AlexWayne No, do not get any compile errors or anything. As you can see on the website, it works, but the Unity game does not show up. Any advice will be a godsend as I have been trying to get this to work for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create an instance of the game. You should call "createUnityInstance" function from Unity loader script ("Build.loader.js" for your game).

To fix this you can use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) and load index.html from Unity build package or create your own loader. For example, for loader, you can use Unity minimal WebGL template code:

```
<canvas id="unity-canvas" width=960 height=600 tabindex="-1" style="width: 960px; height: 600px; background: #231F20"></canvas>
<script src="Build/html5.loader.js"></script>
<script>
  if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // Mobile device style: fill the whole browser client area with the game canvas:
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.name = 'viewport';
    meta.content = 'width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=yes';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);

    var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
    canvas.style.width = "100%";
    canvas.style.height = "100%";
    canvas.style.position = "fixed";

    document.body.style.textAlign = "left";
  }

  createUnityInstance(document.querySelector("#unity-canvas"), {
    dataUrl: "Build/html5.data",
    frameworkUrl: "Build/html5.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "Build/html5.wasm",
    streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
    companyName: "Test",
    productName: "test",
    productVersion: "0.1",
    // matchWebGLToCanvasSize: false, // Uncomment this to separately control WebGL canvas render size and DOM element size.
    // devicePixelRatio: 1, // Uncomment this to override low DPI rendering on high DPI displays.
  });
</script>
```